# node-red not showing nodes (property length undefined)

Tags: node-red

After successful installation of node-red, i have encountered a strange issue. 
No nodes are displayed and there is undefined length issue on console.
[image]

Comment: Have you installed any extra nodes?

Comment: @hardillb no i haven't installed any other extra nodes.

Comment: You might do better asking about this on the mailing list as it will probably take some back and forth to work out what's going on. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red